# Where $|f| <\infty$ a.e. condition is used in Vitali Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

[Vitali convergence theorem_Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem)

Here above is a Wiki article about Vitali convergence theorem, which is referred to Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis.

And I'm wondering where the fourth condition is used to prove the theorem.

4. $ |f(x)| < \infty $ a.e.

Any comments would be helpful. :)

Comment: It is impossible for a function which takes the value $∞$ on a set of positive measure to be $L^1$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks, but then I want to ask whether other three conditions can imply the fourth one. Why can't I prove this without it?